# Confusing Statement from a Derivation of the Convolution of Gaussians

Tags: random-variables, convolution

I was reading a proof of the claim that the convolution of two Gaussians with arbitrary mean and variance results in another Gaussian. It can be found [here](http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf).

At the end of the proof, which I studied in detail, the author claims "the preservation of the normalization when convolving PDFs ... is a special case rather than being true in general."

I take this to mean that the result of the convolution (of 2 normal RV's) being a normal (Gaussian) distribution is somehow not general. But this is certainly not what I understood from the proof - did the author not just prove the result in its full generality (convolution of 2 Gaussian is Gaussian)? Perhaps I missed something in the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you have stated, no, that is not what he meant.
He is saying that the sum of two normal distributions is again normal.
*However this is not always the case.* That is what he is saying. He is saying that this is a coincidence/special for the sum of normals. He is saying that the sum of two $iid$ random variables following some distribution $F$ is not again $F$.
For example, the sum of two $iid$ exponential distributions is not another exponential. If the rates are the same, then it is however a gamma distribution.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. Just to make sure, in the 2nd sentence of your answer, you say "sum of two normal distributions is again normal" - to be more precise, this could be phrased as "convolution of two normal distributions is again normal" or "sum of two independent RV's with normal distributions is again normal", right?

Comment: Yes! In notation, if $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\nu, \tau^2)$ are independent, then
$$X+Y\sim N(\mu+\nu, \sigma^2+\tau^2).$$
Of course, you can generalize to the the sum of $n$ normals.

Comment: Actually, by convolution, _he_ specifically means a sum. As far as I understand, convolution does not always mean sum.